# How to use location sensor of windows 7 and 8?

Tags: windows-8

How to use Windows Sensor and Location Platform of windows  8? Windows 8 has Human Interface Device (HID) protocol and Support for GPS devices.

Curious to know - How to test this functionality? Do we have any OOTB application to check it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just launch the built-in Maps application.

[image]